# MATLAB: Split values in column into 1 or 2 additional columns

Tags: matlab, split

I have a 312x2 matrix representing number of questions answered (column 2) by individual subjects (column 1)
e.g.

```
x =

    40    56
    41    56
    42   176
    43   176
    44   116
    45    56
    46    56
    47   116
    48    56
    49    56
    50   116
```

Some participants answered the questionnaire more than once, and I would like to divide their data into additional columns.

I.e. participant 43 completed it 3 times - 56 questions once, 60 questions twice.

Therefore, I'd like to split their data into 3 columns, to end up with:

```
x = 
    40    56
    41    56
    42    56    60    60
    43    56    60    60
    44    56    60
    ...etc
```

I'll then fill in the gaps with NaN so i can work out the mean questions answered per questionnaire.

Comment: You say the goal is to work out the mean questions answered per questionnaire... do you want to do that first for individual users? If so, consider using `accumarray` with `@mean` as the function - this will generate unique user IDs and the mean questions per user, and you don't need cell arrays or `Nan`-padding to do it.

Comment: @tmpearce I don't think that would work, as Matlab has no way of knowing how many time each user has completed the questionnaire, so `@mean` would have no way of knowing what to divide by. Unless I'm missing something glaringly obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant of solutions, but it gets the job done relatively simply:

```
x = [40 56;41 56;42 176;43 176;44 116;45 56;46 56;47 116;48 56;49 56;50 116];
a=x(:,2);
newData=[];
for i=1:size(a,1)
    if a(i)==56
        newData=vertcat(newData,[56 NaN NaN]);
    elseif a(i)==116
        newData=vertcat(newData,[56 60 NaN]);
    elseif a(i)==176
        newData=vertcat(newData,[56 60 60]);
    end
end
Data = horzcat(x(:,1),newData)
```

Command Window:

```
Data =

40    56   NaN   NaN
41    56   NaN   NaN
42    56    60    60
43    56    60    60
44    56    60   NaN
45    56   NaN   NaN
46    56   NaN   NaN
47    56    60   NaN
48    56   NaN   NaN
49    56   NaN   NaN
50    56    60   NaN
```

Comment: OP's input matrix is of size `[312,2]`. Hard-coding the solution is probably not a viable option.

Comment: It is true that hard coding solutions is almost never the correct way to go about doing something, but in the case where you already know the size of the matrix (or can easily get the size with the size function) and know what the inputs are (or have to be), then I see nothing wrong with doing it this way. It achieves the desired results and is also relatively easy to understand for MATLAB beginners

Comment: This is the only solution that produces the output provided in the original question so +1. I think hard coding is the only way to go here because the rules for splitting the numbers are not provided.

Comment: @Engineer Thanks very much, at the moment this does the trick for me, but it might get more complicated for different values.
Would it work to include ranges in the 'if' loop?
e.g. 
' if a(i)<=60'

Comment: Of course it will get more complicated if your values change, but creating ranges in if loops is easy and will work if you choose to go this route. ex: if a(i)<=60, else if a(i)>60 && a(i)<=100, else if ... etc.

Comment: @Engineer Ah, I missed out the `&&` when i tried that myself. I also can't quite figure out what goes in `newData=vertcat(newData,[*56* NaN NaN]);` instead of `56`.

Comment: if you're expanding upon this method to use ranges, you can just pass in the actual variable value instead of 56: 
    newData=vertcat(newData,[a(i) NaN NaN]); 
Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Engineer Yes, that's exactly what I mean, thanks. If, for example, someone answered only 40 qs the first time, then 60, would it be possible to put a calculation in that code? eg. `newData=vertcat(newData,[(a(i)-60) 60 NaN]);`

Comment: Scratch that, I've tried it, and it seems to have worked! Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Not exactly positive as to what you are trying to do, but yes, you can manipulate the data any way you need. The example you provided above would work: if a(i) was say 40, then `newData=vertcat(newData,[(a(i)-60) 60 NaN]);` will show [-20 60 NaN]

Comment: For that example, the value in the matrix would have been 100, but since they would have answered 60 questions the second time, the number of questions the first time would be `100-60=40`, so the new matrix would show `[40 60 NaN]`. It will definitely get more complicated if participants choose not to answer all the questions in the future (we're expecting up to 1100 subjects over the next few years), but we'll cross that bridge when we come to it. For the moment, hard coding seems to be the way to go. Muchos gracias.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to store the final output, because each row may contain a different number of elements.

Here's a short solution that gives you the desired result:

```
C = mat2cell(x, ones(1, size(x, 1)), 2);
C(ismember(x(:, 1), cellfun(@(z)z(1), y))) = y;
```

where `x` is the original data array as described in the question, and `y` is a cell array with the new lines (as you call them, *split*) to replace in `x`.

#### Example

Here's a brief example similar to the one given in the question:

```
%// Generate sample data
x = [40 56; 41 56; 42 176; 43 176; 44 116; 45 56];
y = {[43 56 60 60]; [44 56 60]};

%// Replace rows in x with matching rows in y
C = mat2cell(x, ones(1, size(x, 1)), 2);
C(ismember(x(:, 1), cellfun(@(z)z(1), y))) = y;
```

The result is a new cell array:

```
C =
    [40    56]
    [41    56]
    [42   176]
    [43    56    60    60]
    [44    56    60]
    [45    56]
```

To calculate the mean questions answered per questionnaire, use `cellfun` to iterate through the cells:

```
m = cellfun(@(x)mean(x(2:end)), C)
```

which for this example yields:

```
m =
   56.0000
   56.0000
  176.0000
   58.6667
   58.0000
   56.0000
```

Comment: Your `x` and the OP's `x` do not have the same form though... in the original question column 1 of x seems to contain unique IDs not repeated for each time the user answers the questionnaire but just the sum

Comment: @Dan Thanks for drawing my attention to this, I guess I misread the question. The solution is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

The following will achieve what you need:

```
B = unique(A(:,1));
m = max(hist(A(:,1),B));
B = [B, nan(numel(B),m)];
for ii=1:size(B,1)
    jj = (A==B(ii,1));
    B(ii,2:end) = [A(jj(:,1),2)', nan(1,m-sum(sum(jj(:,1))))];
end
```

For the input:

```
A =

    53    83
    84    76
    52    99
    53    83
    76    90
    54    73
    91    72
    91    92
    86    54
    57    56
```

The result will be:

```
B =

    52    99   NaN
    53    83    83
    54    73   NaN
    57    56   NaN
    76    90   NaN
    84    76   NaN
    86    54   NaN
    91    72    92
```

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB automatically expands matrices for you when you assign something out of the bounds of the current matrix:

```
>> a = [
    40    56
    41    56
    42   176
    43   176
    44   116
    45    56
    46    56
    47   116
    48    56
    49    56
    50   116];     
>> a(3,3) = 60
a =
    40    56     0
    41    56     0
    42   176    60
    43   176     0
    44   116     0
    45    56     0
    46    56     0
    47   116     0
    48    56     0
    49    56     0
    50   116     0
```

The default action is to pad with zeros (rather than `NaN`s). If you can reasonably expect that there will *never* be any participants who have answered 0 questions, you could do

```
>> a(a==0) = NaN;
>> M = nanmean(a(:,2:end),2);
```

to get the averages.

If you can't expect this (or you don't have /want to depend on the statistics toolbox to use `nanmean`) then you could write a few small functions to do what you want:

```
function new_a = addQsAnswered(old_a, QsAnswered)

    new_a = old_a;

    for ii = 1:size(QsAnswered,1)

        inds = (new_a(:,1) == QsAnswered(ii,1));

        if sum(isnan(new_a(inds,:))) < size(QsAnswered(:,2:end),2)
            new_a = [new_a NaN(size(new_a,1),1)]; %#ok            
        end

        new_a(inds,isnan(new_a(inds,:))) = QsAnswered(ii,2:end);        

    end

end

function M = getParticipantMeans(a)   
    M = zeros(size(a,1),1);    
    for ii = 1:size(a,1)
        as = a(ii,2:end);
        as = as(~isnan(as));
        M(ii) = sum(as)/numel(as);
    end    
end
```

Example:

```
>> addQsAnswered(a, [46 78 90; 49 60 78])
ans =
        40    56   NaN   NaN
        41    56   NaN   NaN
        42   176    60   NaN
        43   176   NaN   NaN
        44   116   NaN   NaN
        45    56   NaN   NaN
        46    56    78    90
        47   116   NaN   NaN
        48    56   NaN   NaN
        49    56    60    78
        50   116   NaN   NaN

>> getParticipantMeans(new_a)
ans =
        5.600000000000000e+001
        5.600000000000000e+001
        1.180000000000000e+002
        1.760000000000000e+002
        1.160000000000000e+002
        5.600000000000000e+001
        7.466666666666667e+001
        1.160000000000000e+002
        5.600000000000000e+001
        6.466666666666667e+001
        1.160000000000000e+002
```